# Matching records between Hive table and Netezza table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, netezza

This is my first question here and I would be really grateful if y'all could help me out.

I ran a sqoop import to transfer a table from Netezza to Hive. Now I have to match the records from the Netezza table to Hive table to check that all the records were successfully imported into hive. I need to make sure each record of one table is matched to another and also find out the unmatched records, if any. My project leader has suggested that I use script to filter the unmatched records and insert into a new tables. (Join both tables by unique key and use ‘where’ to filter the unmatched the records). The problem is I am new to Hadoop and do not know how to go about it.

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The first an foremost is you can run a SELECT query to count the number of recs on the imported Hive table.

```
select count(*) from hive_table;
```

If the counts do not match between the Netezza table and the hive table then you need to first check the logs which were generated during the Sqoop Import. That will give you an insight about the reason why the recs were not loaded.

Comment: I have already run a select count(*) and the number of records match. Is there any way I can access the Netezza table from hive?

Comment: No, i do not think so. The table/data has to be on HDFS for Hive to access it for any computations.